# Discord.py bot not using proper text formatting in embeds, but only on mobile?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's what it looks like on the desktop app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdkTL.jpg

and here's what it looks like on mobile (Android): https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM7WE.jpg

Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def draw(ctx):
    group_of_items = [
                    '[***Seiyaryu***](link)',
                    '[Crawling Dragon #2](link)']
    num_to_select = 2
    list_of_random_items = random.sample(group_of_items, num_to_select)
    first_random_item = list_of_random_items[0]
    second_random_item = list_of_random_items[1]
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f'You drew: {first_random_item}\nand\n{second_random_item}',
        colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(47,128,49)
        )
    embed.set_footer(text="Bot of Greed", icon_url="link")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Any way to fix this so it shows the text formatting on mobile also?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do, and it's been an issue for years now.
I don't have much hope for Discord fixing it.